# How to differ linked clone from a full clone in VirtualBox?

Tags: clone, virtualbox

I've got a list of virtual machines. I know that most of them are only clones of a few base ones. How to determine if a VM is a full clone or a linked clone? Do linked clones have their own disks or are these only differencing images of their base?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically these are the [definitions](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_clone_typeofclone.html):

> - Full-clone: A full clone is an independent copy of a virtual machine that shares nothing with the parent virtual machine after the cloning operation. Ongoing operation of a full clone is entirely separate from the parent virtual machine
> - Linked-clone: A linked clone is a copy of a virtual machine that shares virtual disks with the parent virtual machine in an ongoing manner. This conserves disk space, and allows multiple virtual machines to use the same software installation

Linked clones have their own virtual disk but this is just a differential disk that contains new files or whatever that the parent virtual machine didn't have when the snapshot of that linked clone was created.

The main difference is that full-clone are independent virtual machines and linked-clones are dependent virtual machines because linked clones need the parent virtual disk as their base-virtual-disk.

Comment: Sorry to ask about such an old topic. Is there any performance implications when using linked VM's? If I want 3 VM's, should I create a base VM and then 3 additional linked linked, or just the base one and 2 linked clones?

Comment: @Wes Feel fre to start a new question. However, you should ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) since this topic is not directly related to programming.

Answer (score -6):

Linked Clone is better the full cone why because we are running multiple copy of linked clone still we don't get any issue

fatastic

Thiyagu

Comment: Use correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar to the best of your ability.

Comment: Glad to hear that you are facing no issues with multiple linked clones.. I was wondering the same, if I create a linked clone, will the changes to the linked VM reflect on the host VM?